# Can I duplicate the behavior of one tty on another tty device

Tags: usb, tty

I am currently developing an application that connects to a device via USB but due to project modifications I have to move it to a target device whose only serial communication is via RS-232 [DE-9](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-subminiature) port.

To communicate with the device I use a proprietary API. Using strace I know that it scans all devices in /dev/bus/usb and after finding the right one the API connects to it.

I wanted to know if I could some how emulate my device in /dev/ttyS0 to an unused usb device in /dev/bus/usb/ to connect to it

Comment: Is there a programming question? First off, what language?

Comment: Actually I was trying to do this on shell, I don't have access to the API code, so I can't do anything inside my application to change this behavior. I read a lot about socat, for example, but couldn't find anything like what I am trying to do